# Azure DevOps Release Task to deliberately stop the Release

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm trying to find a release task that I can place inside a Release Pipeline Stage's workflow to intentionally stop the Release.

I have a large provisioning pipeline with 50 tasks per Stage (and 6 Stages). Barring a few exceptions the Stages are identical in Tasks, only differing with variables.

After the 10th task if a variable is true, then I want to stop the Release. This is **not** a failed Release (so I don't want to mark the Release as failed), it just means after the 10th task there is legitimately nothing more to do.

I see lots of information saying create a condition on an existing Task so that the Task only runs when the condition evaluates to true.

This Microsoft documentation suggests to me that on Tasks 11 to 50 I would need a custom condition that says "only run if variable = true". I might have misunderstood the behaviour and there might be another way to achieve the same result.

**Why do I want a Task and not a Condition?**

Conditions seem to cater for pre-conditions, not post-conditions scenarios. If it has to be a condition I'd rather say, "stop the release successfully after the 10th task has completed successfully and the variable = XYZ" using a **post-condition** such as:

*eq(variables['RunTasks11To50'], 'True')*

This is a pain to do this 40 times for a pre-condition (11th task onwards) and it is also error prone as the condition is not obviously set without drilling into the task (unlike a disabled task which is greyed out).

- If there was a "Stop Release" task that allows the Release to legitimately stop then I wouldn't need to add conditions on Tasks 11 to 50.
- Alternatively maybe if there was a "Gate" task that allowed the release to pause and require a confirmation to continue that might work too.

My concern is that I'm going to need to write a condition *eq(variables['RunTasks11To50'], 'True')* on 40 tasks multiplied by 6 stages (6 environments).

**What have I considered?**

- Writing a Powershell task to call the DevOps Rest API to cancel my own Release
- Somehow disabling the Tasks 11 to 50 at runtime (again probably requiring a Powershell Task DevOps Rest API call)
- Wondering if I'm looking for a complicated answer when there's something obvious and simple I've missed.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no "Gate" task to stop the release.

> Alternatively maybe if there was a "Gate" task that allowed the release to pause and require a confirmation to continue that might work too.

We could set Post-deployment conditions or Pre-deployment conditions to add Approvers.

[image]

We recommend that you using condition on Tasks 11 to 50 in the release pipeline and use condition on Stage2 to Stage6 to skip the stage task.

[image]

Also, we could add task power shell tp call the REST API to cancel the release.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining the options, I'm trying to reduce the number of Stages because each Stage logically represents a single environment and most are not related to the other Stages (apart from a PreProd and Production Stage). It appears like Custom Conditions or the Powershell "Cancel" Release options are the most appropriate for my scenarios.